# How to Add Google Code SVN using AnkhSVN to VS2010 Project?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, ankhsvn

I had to format my PC and reinstall Visual Studio 2010. My project is saved in Subversion repository in Google Code.

How do I install the project on my PC to continue working on my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Open a solution from Subversion](http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/com.collabnet.doc.anksvn_001/action/ankh_getting_started.html): **Visual Studio | FILE | Open | Subversion Project...**